# Delete a scheduled task using com objects

Tags: c++, winapi, comobject

I tried the following code for deleting a scheduled task:

```
bool deleteTask(std::wstring taskName)
    {
    if (FAILED(CoInitialize(nullptr))) {
        return false;
    }

    ITaskScheduler *pITS;
    if (FAILED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CTaskScheduler, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskScheduler, (void **)&pITS))) {
        CoUninitialize();
        return false;
    }

    HRESULT hr = pITS->Delete(taskName.c_str());
    pITS->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        if (hr == HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)) {
            wprintf(L"ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND");
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When executing `deleteTask(L"exampletask");` The method `pITS->Delete` returns `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` even though  executing `schtasks.exe /Query /TN exampletask` returns an existing task.
I also tried this code with the privileges of admin / system / service, and none succeed at finding and deleting the task.

Is there some missing parameter, or maybe a method that should be called?
Thanks!

Comment: Probably not immediately related, but the documentation for [ITaskScheduler::Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381820.aspx) reads: *"This API may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of the operating system or product. Please use the [Task Scheduler 2.0 Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383600.aspx) instead."*

Comment: At a guess, you need to specify the full path to the task, where the command line tool implies the tasks root folder if missing. You could try to call `deleteTask(L"\\exampletask");` instead. More information and sample code available from the [ITaskFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381330.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @IInspectable suggested, the solution is to use [Task Scheduler 2.0 Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383600(v=vs.85).aspx),
e.g. `ITaskService` instead of `ITaskScheduler`, and `ITaskFolder->DeleteTask` instead of `ITaskScheduler->Delete`.

```
bool deleteTask(std::wstring taskName)
{
    if (FAILED(CoInitialize(nullptr))) {
        return false;
    }

    ITaskService *pITS;
    if (FAILED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskScheduler, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskService, (void **)&pITS))) {
        CoUninitialize();
        return false;
    }

    if (FAILED(pITS->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t()))) {
        pITS->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return false;
    }

    ITaskFolder *pITF;
    if (FAILED(pITS->GetFolder(_bstr_t(L"\\"), &pITF))) {
        pITS->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return false;
    }

    pITS->Release();

    if (FAILED(pITF->DeleteTask(_bstr_t(taskName.c_str()), 0))) {
        pITF->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return false;
    }

    pITF->Release();

    CoUninitialize();

    return true;
}
```